# EF: Is there any "property changed" event?

Tags: entity-framework, events, properties, handler

I want to do something as soon as my entity (class) changes its Id:

```
[Key]
public int MyId { get; set; }
```

Is it possible?
I would put that handler code within "set" ( `set { ...handler code... }`), but then EF wouldn't map MyId as a column

Answer (score 0):

You can put to setter any handling code you need or fire your custom event. EF just sees that your property has getter and setter and it is all it needs to (and can) now about your entity.